# Problema com o alinhamento do texto

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu estou fazendo um site, porem ele esta com esse problema de espaçamento e alinhamento da foto. Perceba que a parte "treino"esta ok, mas ja na parte "comida" tem um problema no texto (mesmo estando justificado).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Porem o maior problema esta ja no  terceiro topico, da para perceber como o alinhamento do texto esta completamente errado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que ambos estão da mesma maneira e com o mesmos valores, ja que eles são para serem iguais (so muda o nome das classes).

Codigo do paragrafo com a img a direita

```
.t1{
    font-family: "teko";
    font-size: 25pt;
    color: #7843e8;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-top: 8%;
}
.txt1{
    font-family: "roboto";
    text-align: justify;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 45%;
    line-height: 150%;


}
.imgtreino{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 25%;
    bottom: 228px;

}
.btn1{
    font-family: "cabin";
    color: #7843e8;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    border:2px solid #7843e8 ;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn1:hover{
    background-color: #7843e8;
    color: white;
    transition: .5s;

}
```

Codigo do paragrafo com a img a esquerda

```
.t2{
    font-family: "teko";
    font-size: 25pt;
    color: #7843e8;
    margin-top: 10%;
    padding-left: 36%;
}
.txt2{
    font-family: "roboto";
    text-align: justify;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 36%;
    padding-right: 30%;
    line-height: 150%;
}
.imgcomida{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 16%;
    bottom: 228px;

}
.btn2{
    font-family: "cabin";
    color: #7843e8;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    border:2px solid #7843e8 ;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn2:hover{
    background-color: #7843e8;
    color: white;
    transition: .5s;

}
```

Eu ja tentei mudar as positions e não deu certo

codigo HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainT.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/primeiro1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/segundo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/terceiro.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="nav1">
            <img class ="img1" src="imagens/gym freepik - white.png">
            <ul>
                <li id="items1"><a href=""> Treino </a></li>
                <li id="items2"><a href=""> Comidas </a></li>
                <li id="items3"><a href=""> Sono </a></li>
                <li id="items4"><a href=""> Suplementos </a></li>
                <li id="items5"><a href=""> Ergogenicos </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="MainT">
        <p> Curso de Fisiculturismo </p>
    </div>
    <div class="primeiro">
        <p class="t1" id="lk1"> Treino </p>
        <p class="txt1">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel imperdiet nulla. Morbi in venenatis eros, at efficitur sapien. Maecenas rhoncus pellentesque dolor a vulputate. Ut varius velit faucibus nibh elementum, nec iaculis elit pharetra. Integer consectetur elit vitae condimentum venenatis. Sed nec augue accumsan, dignissim nulla tincidunt, maximus arcu. Nulla orci ligula, suscipit semper lacus at, consectetur scelerisque ligula.
        </p>
        <img src="imagens/treino hex.png" class="imgtreino">

        <a href="#" class="btn1"> VER MAIS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="segundo">
        <p class="t2" id="lk2"> Comidas </p>
        <p class="txt2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec magna dui, sodales vel ligula ut, finibus tincidunt mauris. Nulla facilisi. Sed placerat et turpis ac suscipit. Aenean ac urna elementum velit ultrices pellentesque. Donec id vulputate ex, ut auctor enim. Donec dapibus nibh vitae magna facilisis, quis sollicitudin sem molestie. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus ac tincidunt nunc, nec imperdiet justo. Nunc lacus nunc, accumsan sit amet eleifend a, vestibulum vitae lorem. Nam venenatis molestie dui, a molestie mauris lacinia in. Integer sit amet faucibus risus, eget interdum leo.
        </p>
        <img src="imagens/alimen hex.png" class="imgcomida">

        <a href="#" class="btn2"> VER MAIS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="terceiro">
        <p class="t3" id="lk3"> Sono </p>
        <p class="txt3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dictum fringilla neque ut porttitor. Sed a porttitor lorem. Aenean vitae purus ut nisl laoreet feugiat nec vitae dolor. Phasellus vitae odio nisi. Fusce sit amet ex sit amet enim malesuada placerat sit amet ac purus. Quisque in velit sem. Quisque vel justo eget urna dapibus volutpat egestas id metus. Nam condimentum libero arcu, in volutpat lacus pretium sit amet. Nullam sit amet quam pretium, sagittis justo vel, eleifend diam. Pellentesque nec nulla eu quam ultricies lacinia. Praesent nec nisl sit amet purus congue finibus. Etiam orci orci, rutrum ac lacus nec, ultricies euismod neque. Donec finibus purus vel sollicitudin porttitor. Etiam massa tellus, sollicitudin ac odio at, congue tristique lorem.
        </p>
        <img src="imagens/sono hex.png" class="imgsono">

        <a href="#" class="btn3"> VER MAIS</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo e cade o HTML?? Só com o CSS fica complicado te responder, ofereça o mínimo de código que de para a gente simular o seu problema

Comment: esta no post, tinha esquecido

Comment: Coloque `.primeiro, .segundo, .terceiro{
   clear: both;
}` e veja se resolve.

Comment: Amigo desculpe dizer, mas usando float, e padding e margins tipo 20%, 40%, 1%, dificilmente seu layout vai dar certo, e provavelmente vai ficar menos responsivo do que vc imagina. Eu começaria do 0 usando flex. Mas se vc quer seguir com essa ideia (que para mim nunca vai dar certo), procure sobre ClearFix, ele vai resolver seu problema parcialmente

Comment: Deu certo o clear both
Muito obrigado

Comment: Vou ver sobre flex e ver como posso mudar, ainda estou no começo do site

Comment: Lucas então é uma ótima hora para parar e não continuar com algo que não vai dar certo no futuro. É só uma dica...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar floats (`left /right`) é ruim porque o elemento, mesmo estando em outra div, "puxa" também os elementos da div adjacente que nada tem a ver com a história.

É mais recomendável usar [flexbox](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/), que te dá mais poder de organização dos elementos e de quebra ainda te proporciona fazer com mais facilidade um layout responsivo.

Mas para apenas resolver o seu problema, aplique a propriedade `clear: both` nas divs. O `clear` irá impedir que elementos sejam posicionados em ambos os lados do elemento:

```
.primeiro, .segundo, .terceiro{
   clear: both;
}
```

Sem falar que você poderia usar apenas 1 classe no CSS que possuem as mesmas propriedades, evitando códigos repetidos que inflam o arquivo. Por exemplo:

Em vez de criar estilos separados assim:

```
.btn1{
   color: red;
}

.btn2{
   color: red;
}
```

Poderia usar uma classe apenas, já que os dois elementos possuem a mesma propriedade:

```
.btn{
   color: red;
}
```

No caso do `float`, que são diferentes, você cria classes separadas para a propriedade:

```
.f-right{
   float: right;
}

.f-left{
   float: left;
}
```

Por exemplo, o elemento que ficará à esquerda teria:

```
class="btn f-left"
```

E o da direita teria:

```
class="btn f-right"
```